# Multiple background images with initial and url()

Tags: html, css, image, button, background

On my page, I want to have buttons with little icons on the left side of them, something like this:
[image: Edit button example]

The button background should be the default of the browser.

When I just specify my background image, the `initial` background image get's overwritten. So I thought specifing multiple background images would fix the problem:

```
background-image: initial, url("edit.png");
/* background-position .... */
```

But this isn't supported; you can't use `initial` in this context (only `url()` works).

Is there a way to do this favorable without using another image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how I'd achieve the effect you're after:

```
<button>Edit</button>

button:before {
    content: "";
    display: inline-block;
    background-image: url('http://placekitten.com/10/10');
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    margin-right: 5px;
}
```

Result: [image]

**DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/Q76ur/1/**

This will allow you to set a separate background-image for the button as required.

Comment: Thanks. This does only work with `<button>`, right? Is there a way of doing this with an `<input type="submit">`-tag?

Comment: I don't think you can use `:before` or `:after` on `<input />`s... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2587669/css-after-pseudo-element-on-input-field

Comment: That's true but I forgot that you can use `<button type="submit">` instead.